# Disable spinner from moving to last selected item on dropdown

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner where I am adding hint at the bottom(not adding to top as getSelectedItemPosition will consider the hint as well) using arrayadapter hiding it from showing on dropdown options. The problem I am facing is, if I make the hint to show for the first time by using setSelection, then drop will directly go to bottom of the list(though hint won't show). Is there way that the dropdown will always show the top item on dropdown list irrespective of what item I select previously?

Comment: post you code   here